# Python: Create function that iterates through list and returns a copy of list with a number removed

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

I have the following list:

```
listInitial = [20, 33, 24, 11, 0, 4, 3, 11]
```

I'm trying to write a function that iterates through it and returns a copy of this list with 11 removed.  Desired output is: `[20, 33, 24, 0, 4, 3]`

I want to use the append method and for loop in my function.  Below is my code:

```
listSecond = []

def iterateandremove (listInitial, num):
    for i in listInitial:
      if i != num:
        listSecond.append(i)
        print (listSecond)
    
    return (listSecond)


iterateandremove (listInitial, 11)
```

When I run the code it prints the correct list out.  But my function doesn't return anything at all.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you have `listSecond = []` in the function itself

Comment: Are you sure that it's returning anything in the first place? I tried your code and it seems to work.

Comment: Your function is returning something. You're not doing anything with the return value (neither storing it to a name, nor printing it). You haven't told us what you're expecting or how what's happening is wrong (though the `listSecond` defined outside the function is almost certainly wrong, and the `print` shouldn't be there in the production code).

Answer (score 3):

You should define `listSecond` in your function and return it from there.

This way if you run it multiple times, you only return your input list and not all the previous ones combined.

```
def iterateandremove (listInitial, num):
    listSecond = []
    for i in listInitial:
      if i != num:
        listSecond.append(i)
    
    return (listSecond)

removed = iterateandremove(listInitial, 11)
print(removed)
#[20, 33, 24, 0, 4, 3]
```

You could also do this with a simple list comprehension without declaring `listSecond`

```
def iterateandremove(initial, num):
    return [n for n in initial if n != num]
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I run the code it prints the correct list out. But my function doesn't return anything at all. What am I doing wrong?

That's because you didn't assign it to a variable. You'll also want to create a new container within the function, and not use a global variable. Try this:

```
def iterate_and_remove(list_initial, num):
    list_second = []
    for i in list_initial:
        if i != num:
            list_second.append(i)

    return list_second

result = iterate_and_remove([1,2,3,4], 4)
print(result)
```

You could also do this with a list comprehension:

```
list_second = [i for i in list_initial if i != 11]
```

Comment: The OP *did* `return list_second`, so they did in fact `return` something.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I updated my response. Issue was they didnt assign the result of the function call to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative;

```
listInitial = [20, 33, 24, 11, 0, 4, 3, 11]
def iterateandremove(listInitial, num):

    return list(filter((num).__ne__, listInitial))

print(iterateandremove(listInitial, 11))
[20, 33, 24, 0, 4, 3]
```

lambda function also a good candidate for this;

```
listInitial = [20, 33, 24, 11, 0, 4, 3, 11]
def iterateandremove(listInitial, num):

    return list(filter(lambda digit: digit != num, listInitial))

print(iterateandremove(listInitial, 11))
[20, 33, 24, 0, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems ok and the function is returning the list without 11.

```
returnedList = iterateandremove (listInitial, 11)
print(returnedList) #[20, 33, 24, 0, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
def iterateandremove(listInitial, num):
    return [n for n in listInitial if n != num]

listInitial = [20, 33, 24, 11, 0, 4, 3, 11]
print(iterateandremove(listInitial, 11))
```

If you are using python3, the list comprehension would do the work for you like the code above.

If you are using python2, I would suggest using python3 instead, for more details, see https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/